# How to fix "Type Error" axios in React JS

Tags: reactjs, axios

My issue is that i am getting a type error whenever i try parameters to this api https://scryfall.com/docs/api/cards/collection

I've tried some debugging but i can't quite seem to get the response.

https://codesandbox.io/s/r5515135zo

```
axios({
      api: "https://api.scryfall.com/cards/collection",
      method: "post",
      identifiers: [{ name: "banefire" }, { set: "m19" }]
    })
      .then(function(response) {
        // your action after success
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(function(error) {
        // your action on error success
        console.log(error);
      });
  };
```

Trying to get a response without an error in console.

Comment: Have you tried `url` instead of `api`? I don't think `api` is a valid key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per [axios' docs](https://github.com/axios/axios), a JSON post request is done as such:

```
axios.post({ /* JSON data */ })
```

You should thus replace the code you included by the following:

```
axios.post('https://api.scryfall.com/cards/collection', {
    identifiers: [{
      name: "banefire"
    }, {
      set: "m19"
    }]
  })
  .then(console.log)
  .catch(console.log);
```

Or, if you want to save the API response in a global variable - let's say, `myGlobalVar` to be super original:

```
const myGlobalVar = null;

axios.post('https://api.scryfall.com/cards/collection', {
  identifiers: [{ name: "banefire" }, { set: "m19" }]
})
.then(responseData => myGlobalVar = responseData)
```

---

Note that in your answer, you included `identifiers` as an axios parameter, not part of the data you'll pass to the API.

Comment: ty so much but how do i store the data

Comment: What do you mean by storing the data?

Comment: (on a side note - it's weird for new Stack Overflow users, but please avoid writing thank you in a comment! Instead, upvote or accept the answer - [here's why](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers))

Comment: I meant to click accept, but the .post array response where can i store it.

Comment: Well, that's a pretty large question :) you can store it in the localStorage, in your redux store, in your component state, in a local variable, in a global variable...

Comment: Fair enough i should be specific. I would like to store in a global var. How could I pass the response to the variable?